# Sql Bat File - authenticate using Windows

Tags: jquery, sql, batch-file, authentication

I have this bat script for executing some sql files from a folder.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET SQLCMD="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE"
SET PATH="C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\sqls"
SET SERVER="DB1"
SET DB="database_name"
SET LOGIN="DOMAIN\user.name"
SET PASSWORD="password"
SET OUTPUT="C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\OutputLog.csv"

CD %PATH%

ECHO %date% %time% > %OUTPUT%

for %%f in (*.sql) do (
%SQLCMD% -S %SERVER% -d %DB% -U %LOGIN% -P %PASSWORD% -i %%~f >> %OUTPUT% -b -h-1 -s";" -w 700
)
```

The script doesn't work when I have to use the "Authenticate using Windows" 'though i'm specifying the domain.

Is there something wrong with my script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RUNAS` and execute the `SQLCMD -E` to run as a different user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your .bat file as the domain user that will be connecting to the database... and use the -E (case sensitive) switch on the SQLCMD executable.

You can shift-right-click and Run as a Different User or your can script it... `runas.exe /user:domain\username somefile.cmd.`